# como hacer un grafico de lineas (X,Y) con sql server en c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2014, charts

Tengo la siguiente consulta Sql donde quiero que Weight sea el eje Y y La fecha sea el eje X

La idea es mostrar el peso de el usuario a través del tiempo que ha usado la aplicación:

```
select * from UserWeight where UserWeight.UserID=2 order by UserWeight.LastUpdate asc
```

no tengo idea de como realizar un chart de esta manera, encuentro de filas y columnas pero nunca encuentro como hacer uno lineal

Comment: Dos preguntas... Por qué no te es útil la información como te viene en el Select? Tienes datos de prueba que podamos utilizar?

Comment: si es útil, es el progreso que llevo hasta ahora, pero no se como hacer el chart de esa manera, por que me salen es de tipo circular y de columnas o filas pero no encuentro el control para hacerlo de manera con ejes X y Y

Comment: datos de prueba puedes usar 1,2,3,4,5 y fechas secuenciales la idea es hacer una grafica que tienda a la subida